# How to use Couchbase Java SDK to modify a document in a bucket without changing its "expiration" value?

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have to modify a document in the Couchbase bucket using the Java SDK (currently it is a Java client in version 2.7.7 however, this can be changed if necessary) without changing its “expiration” value. There are no indexes in the bucket, and N1QL queries are not an option, so I have to stick with key /value operations.

Here is minimal example describing what is the problem, and what I’ve tried so far:
I have a json document in the bucket, which has been created using Java SDK:

```
JsonObject obj = JsonObject.create()
    //Setting some essential data ... 
    .put(“lessImportant”, “This shouldn’t influence on the expiration time”);
int expiry = ((int)Instant.now().getEpochSecond()) + someOffset;
JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.create("msg::42", expiry, obj);
bucket.insert(doc);
```

I would like to get this object and modify it’s “lessImportant” property but I don’t want to change “expiration” value in the metadata of the object while I’m doing this.

When I try just to set the property and resend the object:

```
JsonDocument doc = bucket.get(“msg::42”)
doc.content.put(“otherData”, “I hope expiration remains the same”);
bucket.upsert(doc);
```

or create new one without specifying expiration value:

```
JsonObject obj = oldDoc.content();
obj.put(“otherData”, “I hope expiration remains the same”);
JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.create(oldDoc.id(), obj);
bucket.upsert(doc);
```

or the same with upsert() replaced by replace(), then I can see that every time the document is being updated its “expiration” value is being removed (It is set to 0 which for Couchbase means that after insertion it should treat this document as it has no expiration date set at all – the document should remain persisted forever)

As I’ve observed whenever I create JsonDocument and not set “expiration” explicitly :

```
JsonDocument.create(String id, int expiry, JsonObject data);
```

then by default this value is being set to 0 :

```
JsonDocument.create(String id, JsonObject data); //0 is the default`
```

Moreover it turned out that no matter what is real expiration time inside the bucket, `bucket.get(String id)` returns document with always the same value of “expiration” property which is 0 (Is it a bug of the SDK, or just expected behavior?), so when I’m trying upsert retrieved doc the “expiration” is 0:

```
bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create(
    “msg::123”, SOME_EXPIRATION, obj));//sets expiration SOME_EXPIRATION
bucket.upsert(bucket.get(“msg::123”));//resets expiration to 0
```

Is it possible to either update a document in a way which doesn’t modify this particular  metadata or get the old “expiration” value so it can be set to the correct value before insertion?

Comment: The easiest solution is to move to the new 3.x Java client, currently in alpha but planned to go GA in the coming months.  We've added explicit support for passing through the expiration value which you can see here https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/3.0/howtos/kv-operations.html#expirationttl.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Expiration time in your base class, at the time when SDK is reading the document by extending **AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration** and set it back when this type of document is writing, an example is given below

```
import com.ishfaqhaider.MyCustomClass;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.CouchbaseDocument;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.config.EnableCouchbaseRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"com.ishfaqhaider"})
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

@Bean
@Override
public MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter() throws Exception {
    final MappingCouchbaseConverter converter = new MyCouchbaseConverter(couchbaseMappingContext());
    return converter;
}

static class MyCouchbaseConverter extends MappingCouchbaseConverter {
    @Override
    public <R> R read(final Class<R> clazz, final CouchbaseDocument source) {
        R r= super.read(clazz, source);
        if(clazz==MyCustomClass.class){
        ((MyCustomClass)r).setExpiration(source.getExpiration());
        }
        return r;
    }
    @Override
    public void write(final Object source, final CouchbaseDocument target) {
        if(source instanceof MyCustomClass){
            target.setExpiration(((MyCustomClass)source).getExpiration());
        }
        super.write(source, target);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hello @Ishfaq, does this work on your machine? I hadn’t use spring-data-couchbase before, so maybe I'm missing something, but I’ve created fresh Spring Boot 2.1.7 project with spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase, and config similar to yours, and I found out that source.getExpiration() in MyCouchbaseConverter.read() method returns always 0 (even tough other fields are correct, and good "expiration" is visible in metadata from Couchbase UI). Maybe I should set some additional config? I’ve tried this with fresh installation of Couchbase Server 6.0 CE.